# What is the `hello world` of image generation?

Tags: image-generation, examples, machine-learning

When getting started programming, traditionally a student's first program prints "hello world" to the console. In case you are unfamiliar with the common practice, [Rosetta Code has a hello world exercise for beginners](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Newbie).

What is the simplest graphical generative AI model that someone could write from scratch and run on any personal computer?

The bar for output is *real low*, here. There should be few lines of code and classes. No hardware arch should be assumed. Output should be trivial and obvious, but probably not actually useful (like "hello world"). Basic principles of generative modeling should be represented. How well it works does not matter, so long as it demonstrates theory. It could even be pseudocode, so long as it would be trivial for a beginner to translate it to a language they know.

Prerequisite knowledge can be assumed (like linear algebra), and *those* kinds of dependencies could certainly be declared. A `hello world` would not import PyTorch or any *specific* AI library, but could rely on such interfaces with multiple implementations.

Maybe this question could have as many answers as there are demonstrable generative algorithms; I am tempted to ask for the simplest stable diffusion example I can read. But I am asking someone knowledgeable to ***pick*** what to ***start*** with.

Comment: I think "from scratch" ("would not import pytorch or any AI library") combined with "few lines of code" might make this difficult. To be understandable for learning it may make more sense to implement backpropogation/gradient descent/conv layers/u-nets/etc. from scratch on their own, which could each be a relatively readable example, but then go up a level of abstraction (pytorch or similar) for creating a diffusion model. // Also, as this site is for users of genai tools rather than developement of them, it may be better to ask in ai.stackexchange.com or datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Okay, good feedback @SirBenet. I still think an answer should exist, declaring lower-level functions (like what you mention such as back propagation…) as out of scope. Are there no standard interfaces, at least, for such common old algorithms? Also, thanks for pointing out ai.stackexchange. I did not know of it. If I paste this over there would that be frowned-upon?

Comment: "Are there no standard interfaces, at least, for such common old algorithms" - It's not 1-1 in PyTorch/Tensorflow/JAX/etc. as far as I'm aware, but allowing answers to use some 'generic machine learning framework' with conv layers/backprop/etc. could make it feasible for readers to adapt. // "If I paste this over there would that be frowned-upon?" - I think there's a mechanism for moving posts, but reputation-gated. Could flag your own post to request a moderator to move it.

Comment: I think this question would fit better (and get better answers) on https://ai.stackexchange.com/. GenAI is more focused on the usages of generative AI, not on creating AI models.